# Is it correct to put adverb between the phrasal verb?

Tags: grammar

> "Many people **spend** money **extravagantly** **on** frivolous products that they
>   do not really need such as discount fashion items from well-known
>   brands"

I would like to ask whether it is grammatically correct or natural to put the adverb **"extravagantly"** between the verb and the preposition like in the sentence given.

It sounds quite natural to me, but I still feel a bit weird, perhaps I have never seen this before. So please let me know your opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is quite grammatical and such constructions are often used  by native and fluent speakers. If you like, you can think of "spend money extravagantly" as a new phrasal verb.