# What types of adverbs could be put between a phrasal verb?

Tags: adverbs

[From an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/217911/116345)

> ... (put adverb between the phrasal verb) is quite grammatical and such constructions are often used by native and fluent speakers.

I strongly agree with this, as I've seen quite a lot of examples of it.

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sort-sth-sb-out)

> sort sth/sb out: to **deal successfully with** a problem, a situation, or a person who is having difficulties

"Deal successfully with" is a good example of that grammar point. The question is what types of adverbs could be put between a phrasal verb?

According to [English Grammar Today on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types), there are a few of different types of adverbs, like

1. Time, place and manner adverbs
2. Degree adverbs and focusing adverbs
3. Evaluative adverbs
   ...

Which of those types could be put between a phrasal verb?

Comment: There are separable and inseparable phrasal verbs. You might look to the particular phrasal verb rather than to the type of adverb, though it would have to be a semantic fit. 
"Between" requires two objects, so you might say "between the parts of a phrasal verb".

Comment: Most linguists would not call _deal with_ a phrasal verb because it doesn't do particle shift: i.e, *_He hasn't dealt it with yet_ is ungrammatical, while _He hasn't dealt with it yet_ is grammatical. A "true" phrasal verb like _look up_ has the opposite pattern: _He hasn't looked it up yet_ but *_He hasn't looked up it yet._

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. Would you please provide some reference, like, [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deal-with-sth)?

Comment: @RobertH John Lawler *is* the reference. ;)

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. Is it some kind of difference between AmE and BrE?  [The Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deal-with-sth) indeed considers a phrasal verb.

Comment: Dictionaries are not grammars and are not authoritative on grammatical terminology. They tend to use their own terms and definitions, instead of linguistic terms. Many teachers and textbook authors also use their own unstandardized terminology. The result is that one has to rely on syntactic tests like particle shift to distinguish the true, the blushful phrasal verb from one of several types of prepositional phrase constructions after different verbs.